# Photoshop: how to save cut out to JPG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, transparency, jpg, image-format

I did cut out pictures white background and I expect to save it to jpg file without background. I do export and save to jpg. Unfortunately I still have background in new file. How to fix it?

[image]

I would like to ommit white frame around PCB board

[image]

Answer (score 4):

JPG files cannot be transparent. Transparency will always default to white whenever a JPG is generated.

Save as transparent PNG instead via Save for Web: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then choose PNG-24 and tick the 'Transparency' option.